# Contact form plugin - if errors jumps to top of page

Tags: plugin-contactform

Using the standard form plugin can you redirect for errors to a id, which works for the submission confirmation (success)?

```
 {{ redirectInput('#contact') }}
```

My form is half way down the page so jumps you to the top when it has errors.

Full code:

```
 <div class="cta-section" id="contact">
  <div id="thanks" role="alert">
{% if craft.app.session.hasFlash('notice') %}
    <div class="alert-thanks"><p class="message notice"><strong>{{ craft.app.session.g*emphasized text*etFlash('notice') }}</strong></p></div>
{% elseif craft.app.session.hasFlash('error') %}
    <div class="alert-error"><p class="message error"><strong>{{ craft.app.session.getFlash('error') }}</strong></p></div>
{% endif %}
</div>


      {% macro errorList(errors) %}
    {% if errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import errorList %}

<div class="text-left">
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact-form/send">
    {{ redirectInput('#contact') }}

<div class="w-full md:flex ">
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 mb-4 md:mr-6">  

      <h3 class="float-left w-full uppercase"><label for="from-name">Name</label></h3>
      <input id="from-name" type="text" name="fromName" class="w-full" value="{{ message.fromName ?? '' }}">
      {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}

    </div>

    <div class="w-full mb-4 md:w-1/2">  

      <h3 class="uppercase"><label for="from-email">Email</label></h3>
      <input id="from-email" type="email" name="fromEmail" class="w-full" value="{{ message.fromEmail ?? '' }}">
      {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}
    </div>

  </div>


<div class="w-full clearfix"> 
    <h3 class="uppercase"><label for="message">Message</label></h3>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="message" name="message" class="clearfix">{{ message.message ?? '' }}</textarea>
    {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('message')) }}
  </div>

    <div class="mt-4 clear text-center"><input type="submit" value="Send"></div>
</form>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML element whose id is "contact"?

Comment: It is wrapped in a <div id="contact"> updated above.